# Can someone explain this 'Get all Numeric Elements' operator Predicate Filter?

Tags: xslt-1.0

Trying to get elements with a value that is numeric, including zero.

**sample xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PRODUCTS xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <PRODUCT>      
        <REFERENCE>10</REFERENCE>
        <ATTRIBUTES />
        <TITLE>fdg</TITLE>
        <ACTIVE>1</ACTIVE>
        <DELETE>0</DELETE>
        <STOCK>10</STOCK>
        <WEIGHT>0.00</WEIGHT>
        <MODEL>f</MODEL>
        <EAN />
        <MPN />
        <ISBN />
        <UPC />
        <PRICE>10.000</PRICE>
        <SALE_PRICE>10.000</SALE_PRICE>
        <RRP_PRICE>0.000</RRP_PRICE>
        <COST_PRICE>0.000</COST_PRICE>
        <VAT_RATE>0.00</VAT_RATE>            
  </PRODUCT>  
</PRODUCTS>
```

**Expected Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Values>
    <REFERENCE>10</REFERENCE>
    <ACTIVE>1</ACTIVE>
    <DELETE>0</DELETE>
    <STOCK>10</STOCK>
    <WEIGHT>0.00</WEIGHT>
    <PRICE>10.000</PRICE>
    <SALE_PRICE>10.000</SALE_PRICE>
    <RRP_PRICE>0.000</RRP_PRICE>
    <COST_PRICE>0.000</COST_PRICE>
    <VAT_RATE>0.00</VAT_RATE>
</Values>
```

- 'all numeric' `[number()]` returns 0 as single predicate expression

```
<xsl:template match="/">
<Value>

<xsl:for-each select="//*[number()]">
            <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:element>
```

- Excluding elements without descendants produces expected (non-zero) numbers

```
<xsl:for-each select="//*[number() and not(descendant::*)]">
```

- Get all 0 using `*[number() or format-number(text(),0)='0']`

non-zero numbers
`<xsl:for-each select="//*[number() and not(descendant::*)]">`

all numbers
`<xsl:for-each select="//*[number() or format-number(text(),0)='0']">`

Adding an additional **and** or **or** seems to produce the expected.
Why does `select="*[number()]"` output 0 results, until an and/or is added?

Answer (score 2):

The rules for evaluating the expression in a [predicate](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#predicates) are as follows:

1. If the expression evaluates to a number $n, then the result is true if  $n is equal to the context position; IOW, it is as if you have written `[position() = $n]`;
2. Otherwise the expression is evaluated as a boolean.

To demonstrate, consider the following simplified example:

**XML**

```
<items>
    <item>0</item>
    <item>x</item>
    <item>3</item>
    <item>y</item>
    <item>4</item>
</items>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/items">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="item[number()]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<items>
   <item>3</item>
</items>
```

Here only the item whose value, when converted to a number, matches the item's position was copied.

---

If instead you do:

```
        <xsl:copy-of select="item[number() or false()]"/>
```

then the result will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<items>
   <item>3</item>
   <item>4</item>
</items>
```

because now the expression is evaluated as a boolean and any number other than 0 will be evaluated as `true`.

---

In order to copy all items with a "numeric" value, you need to do:

```
        <xsl:copy-of select="item[number() = number()]"/>
```

to get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<items>
   <item>0</item>
   <item>3</item>
   <item>4</item>
</items>
```

This excludes the items whose value cannot be converted to a number - because NaN is not equal to anything, including itself.

Answer (score 0):

When you evaluate `number()` in a predicate, it is behaving as if you had specified the short-hand for the position. i.e. for `<REFERENCE>10</REFERENCE>` it was as if you had tested `//*[10]` or the longer form `//*[position()=10]` and that element is at position 1 and not 10, so it didn't select any elements.

Another way to evaluate a boolean expression and test if they are numeric would be to use:

```
[number() eq number()]
```

Comment: Thanks Mads  removing the number() predicate, the format-number() zero check returns only zeroes, so the number() predicate does return numbers when accompanied.  

So only when left as a single clause it's interpreted as position?  
Does that mean the expression you shared is how number() is interpreted when it's NOT the only condition?  

Wondering why number() is interpreted in different ways, and if the other way you shared is the only other method.  

*[number()] = *[position() = number()]
*[number() or ...] = *[number() = number() or ...]